# How to make 3 different color on Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

i use highcharts for my project, for now i just can make 2 different color. blue when the value >= 0 and red for negative.

[image: charts]

is there a way to make it into 3 colors ?
so when the value = 0 the color become green
i tried using "linkedTo" that demonstrated by someone on [there](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yHn2D/) but my data[] is dynamic.

```
$(function () {
      $('#jugernaut<?php echo $a; ?>').highcharts({
            chart: {
                  type: 'column',
                   spacing:[0,0,0,0],
      height: 450
            },
            title: {
                  text: '<?php echo $key->carline.' '.$key->conveyeor ?>',
                  style: {
                            fontSize: '18px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                  }
            },
    yAxis: 
    {     visible: false,
      tickLength:1, 
           title: {
           text: ''
             },
      labels: {
    style: {
      fontSize: '17px',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    plotLines: [{
        color: '#C0C0C0',
        width: 5,
        value: 0
    }]

  },
     },
    xAxis:{
     tickInterval:1,
     labels: {
    style: {
      fontSize: '17px',
       fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
  }
   },
        credits: {
                text: '',
    enable:false,
     
          },
  plotOptions:{

    marker:{
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  series: [
  {
    name: ' ',
    type: 'spline',
    data: <?php echo json_encode(${"jamnya".$i});?>,
    color: '#1122DD',
    threshold: 0,
    negativeColor: 'red',
  }
  ]
    });
});
```

*sorry if my english so bad

Comment: Tricky, but you could use [`zones`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones) like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/7sj67gs6/3/. It does not behave perfect around zero though.

Comment: yes i still can see red or blue line behind green if there's more than one zero value but your answer save my day. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use `zones` feature for example, to define the colors for three levels of values. Here is the example code:

```
series: [{
        data: [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 10, 10, 5, 0, -5],
        zones: [{
            value: 0,
            color: 'red'
        }, {
            value: 0.000001,
            color: 'green'
        }, {
            color: 'blue'
        }]
}]
```

Also, you can achieve that by adding `color: 'green'` property directly to the `0`point, just like that:

```
series: [{
    data: [-10, -5, {y:0, color: 'green'}, 5, 10, 15, 10, 10, 5, {y:0, color: 'green'}, -5],
    zones: [{
        value: 0,
        color: 'red'
    }, {
        color: 'blue'
    }]
}]
```

Here are the examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/ggxmo9n1/

http://jsfiddle.net/0s8oukLv/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.zones

Comment: very good explanation. thanks although i still can see red and blue line behind green if there's zero value close together